# Docker Desktop - Set "Open in Browser" default page

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

When you click on the "Open In Browser" button, the site opened is *localhost:port*.
Is there any way to change this to open a specific page? (like *localhost:port/swagger/index.html* )

I'm creating the images using docker-compose in VS 2019 and have the default page set to swagger, and upon compiling it opens, but when clicking from Docker Desktop it doesn't

Comment: See also https://forums.docker.com/t/how-does-docker-desktop-compute-the-url-to-be-used-by-open-in-browser-command/116629 (but no solution yet).

Answer (score 0):

VS Code Docker Plugin has the same feature and I assume it would mirror the functionally.

It is implemented in [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/commit/de73eeb3ca7741ef50ed40d4457191a7361f4531) however the URL never sets a page only a port so it looks like it is not possible.

```
 const url = `${protocol}://${host}:${mappedPort.HostPort}`;
```